# Slidetoggle? Not sure of the name

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

Was looking to add a note at the top of my webpage similar to this closing letter found here: http://cypher13.com/ I was curious if anyone knew about any javascript/jquery plugin that could achieve this effect? Something simple if possible. My javascript skills are a bit on the beginner side :)  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Name of the method is slideToggle, there are some examples here http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a plugin for that:

HTML:

```
<div><a id="close" href="javascript:void(0);">close</a></div>
<div id="content">content</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {

   $('#close').click(function() { $('#content').slideUp(1000); });

});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/KusAk/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, it is `slideToggle`. Example:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head> ... </head>
  <body>
      <div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
      <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>   
   </body>
</html>
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
      });
 });
```

CSS:

```
#panel,#flip {
   padding:5px;
   text-align:center;
   background-color:#e5eecc;
   border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
#panel {
   padding:50px;
   display:none;
}
```

Reference:
http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/